# Wildfly 10 server size increasing on Openshift

Tags: github, openshift, wildfly, git-push, openshift-client-tools

I have a wildfly 10 server running on openshift server. The problem I am having is that the wildfly server is continuously increasing its size every time I `git push` my code to the server.

I tried to debug this problem my keeping only one deployment and invoking the `rhc app-tidy` command. I also tried to `force-clean-build`. However, after trying all of this, the size of the server still increases every time I git  push.

I sshed into my server and saw that the wildfly folder size keeps on increasing everyone I `git push`.

Is there a particular reason for this error, and how can I solve it?

Thank you for your assistance and I appreciate it.

Comment: Could you identify files which consume more disk space each time you push/deploy your app? Are you versioning built packages to be deployed such as .war files?

Comment: Yes, the server deploy the ROOT.war file every time I build

Comment: The files that increase in size overtime I `git push` are the `wildly` file/folder itself, the `wildfly/standalone` file, and the `wildfly/standalone/data` file

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a correct behavior. When you push your code, it is built and deployed into the server directory structure (`standalone/` for WildFly 8+). So it is at two places then:

- in your git repo
- in the server directory structure

Basic info about how to deploy wars directly into `standalone/` without using git, thus saving some storage space, can be found [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-deployment-options.html#_deploying_your_war_and_ear_files_using_scp_sftp).

Answer (score 0):

You should post an issue to the github repository for that community cartridge (https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge).  You could also try sending an email to one of the WildFly mailing lists for help with this issue.